# Angular Find the selector of an element to change the color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a button, `mat-form-field` select button, and my problem is to change its color. I can't find the proper selector for that.

The button styles is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRX4S.png)

**app.component.html**

```html
<div id="zoneButtonZone">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Zone" (selectionChange)="updatePlayerZone($event)" style="font-family: beaufort, serif;font-size: 16px">
            <mat-option value="br">BR</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="eune">EUNE</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I tried the following `CSS` codes, but it doesn't work:

**app.component.css**

```css
#zoneButtonZone.mat-form-field-infix {
  background: white;
}
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-infix {
  background: white;
}
#zoneButtonZone > mat-form-field > div > div.mat-form-field-flex.ng-tns-c49-1 > div {
  background: white;
}
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-infix {
  background: white;
}
.mat-form-field-type-mat-select:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex {
  background: white;
}
```

I don't know what's the selector to change the background color. I tried all the selectors.

Comment: Are you using this css inside the component style sheet or inside the style.css.

Comment: Try using - ::ng-deep {.mat-form-field-type-mat-select:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex {
  background: white;

} }

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a class to your button and use that class in the css.

e.g.

```
<div id="zoneButtonZone">
  <mat-form-field class="select-btn">
          <mat-select placeholder="Zone" (selectionChange)="updatePlayerZone($event)">
            <mat-option value="br">BR</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="eune">EUNE</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and then in your css, you can specify:

```
.select-btn {
  background-color: white;
}
```